# if an aws spot instance is stopped by AWS and then restarts will it just start where it left off?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am running luigi, a pipeline manager which is processing 1000 tasks. Currently I poll for the AWS termination notice. If it is present then I requeue the job; wait 30 minutes; then launch a new server starting all the tasks from scratch. However sometimes it restarts the same job multiple times which is inefficient.

Instead I am considering using create_fleet with InstanceInterruptionBehaviour=Stop? If I do this then when it restarts will it still be running the luigi daemon and retain the state of all the tasks?

Comment: It would be like if it was running on your laptop, and you literally turned off your laptop and then turned it back on later. Anything in RAM would be wiped. The operating system and all apps will have to start back up. I have no idea what "luigi" is, so I don't know if it would start up from where it left off, but it would have to be saving its state to hard drive on shutdown and reading that on startup, in order for that to work, so you would have to look into configuring your app to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `InstanceInterruptionBehaviour=Stop` does is effectively shutdown your EC2 instance rather than terminate it. Since the ["persistent" setting is required in addition to EBS storage"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/stop-spot-instances.html) you will keep all the data currently on the attached EBS volumes at the time of the instance stop.

It is completely dependent on the application itself (Luigi in this case) to be able to store the state of its execution and pick back up from where it left off. For one, you'll want to ensure you enable the service daemon to automatically start upon system start (example):

```
sudo systemctl enable yourservice
```